# ajax call not hitting MVC Action Result

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a ajax call that needs to hit my MVC Action Result.
I am getting the success method to fire.  It shows the ID that I'm wanting.  When I debug my breakpoint is never hit, nor does the method logic fire (redirect to Google in this case).

Basically, I have a list of songs and when the play icon is clicked, I want the Id passed to my controller through ajax so I can count it and save the play count to my database.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.playbtn').click(function () {
        var clickedSongId = $(this).find('i').data('songid');
        var fightsong = { Id: clickedSongId };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePlayCount", "Team")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //data: fightsong,
            data: fightsong,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { alert('Success'); },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(clickedSongId);}
        });            
    });
});
```

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePlayCount(int id)
 {
    return Redirect("http:www.google.com");
 }
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. It does not redirect. Just do a normal submit.

Comment: Yes, I get that. THe point of that being there is to just be a placeholder to see if I'm even hitting the method, which I'm not

Comment: As Jason has indicated in his answer, it you use `contentType: json` then you need to stringify the data. Otherwise just remove the `contentType:` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the data

`data: JSON.stringify(fightsong)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdatePlayCount", "Team")';
var clickedSongId = $(this).find('i').data('songid');
var fightsong = { Id: clickedSongId };

jQuery.ajax(url, {type: 'POST', data: fightsong}).done(function(data)
{
    //write code with javascript if you want redirect
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
{
     //write code to handle error
});
```